# ssh-host-config reset after reboot and shh -vvv localhost /ipaddress not working

Tags: cygwin

I have configure ssh-host-config  in cygwin 
cygcheck (cygwin) 2.4.1..

When I have setup ssh-host-config on windows 7 , ssh login is working to my system.afer reboot of System ssh loging is not working and localhost checking is failed with below logs.

Please help if you have solved this issue.

ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/psing/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/psing/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/psing/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/psing/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/psing/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 3
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/psing/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/psing/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/psing/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'psing'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com  none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com  none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Khz11YkVERoV1mlVERovPEm/x/AeLaUJveN49ig+Ag0
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/psing/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/psing/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/psing/.ssh/id_dsa for not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: Offering ECDSA public key: /home/psing/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/psing/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
psing@localhost's password:

Answer (score 0):

Username is *case sensitive*.

The username was created in `.shh`  directory was case sensitive.

So when login to SSH host system, careful with username created in in SSH directory.